# Debian Stretch IPv6 prioritization

Tags: ipv6, ipv4, debian-stretch

I have a Debian Stretch system with both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses and default gateway. IPv4 and IPv6 addresses in the internet are reachable. When I start a ping to a domain which has an A and AAAA DNS record the system pings the IPv4 address from the A record. In the packet capture of the DNS request I can see that both A and AAAA are requested and answered.
When I remove the IPv4 address from the system obviously everything works as expected....

How is the prioritization, I thought IPv6 will be preferred. If not, is there a option to change it?

A google search has not really helped me out because everyone asks to disable IPv6 and not want to use it...

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I try to ping on Debian stretch, it pings the IPv6 address. Please tell us every detail about your system.

Answer (score 0):

By default resolver should prefer ipv6 addresses over ipv4. But there was a bug in the debian, that prefer ipv4 over ipv6 in some cases. Also this behaviour can be managed with `/etc/gai.conf` file (named from syscall `getaddrinfo`).

Comment: Can you please link to the Debian bug?